# Why is Gimp Eraser erasing two layers?

Tags: gimp, layers

I have 2 separate layers for the original eye background i called *eyes-outline* and another layer for my new eyes i called *white-eyes*. It's obvious that they are separate layers as in the left image I have white-eyes invisible and on the right image I have *eyes-outline* invisible.

[image]

But when I have *white-eyes* selected and try to erase the white area, it also erases the other layer *eyes-outline* layer. How is that possible that the eraser is manipulating 2 layers at the same time? I thought Gimp only can operate on 1 active selected layer? Even when I set the *eyes-outline* layer invisible and try to erase the white-eyes layer, and then make the eyes-outline visible again, it is erased as well... so it is impossible for me to erase only the white without affecting the other layer no matter if visible or invisible. Is that a bug?

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! Yes the flesh part is also part of the layer of the original eyes. I double checked and made sure I have exactly those layers. Now all of a sudden it works normal again.  I believe there was some bug... although I cannot 100% be certain..

Comment: Have you checked that all layers modes are set to Normal, and that the `Composite Mode` (right click the layer in the Layers menu) is set to `Auto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this problem. The eraser only erases the selected layer, and works as expected.

Having a look at your layers panel I notice that the layer named "Eyes outline" seems to contain some flesh coloured pixels. So, that's where I would check first to see what is going on.

Perhaps try increasing the size of your Layer Panel thumbnails so you can see them better. Or switch off other layers to make sure exactly what you have on those layers. It's very easy to lose track of what you painted on different layers.

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! Yes the flesh part is also part of the layer of the original eyes. I double checked and made sure I have exactly those layers. Now all of a sudden it works normal again. I wonder what that mysterious behavior was all about... I wish I could share the file though XD but thank you again, increasing the layers is definitely helpful